# Selenium(PYTHON) check whether or not element exists

Tags: python, html, selenium, webautomation

So im trying to figure out how to run this loop properly, my issue is that depending on the link that is loading, the page that loads will have an access denied error, this isnt like that for all the links, my issue is that i would like to identify whether or not when a particular element loads onto my screen, the program recognizes it and breaks the loop, and starts the next iteration in the for loop, so im trying to determine whether the "Access-Denied" element is present, and if it is, then break, otherwise, continue the for loop

```
idList = ["8573", "85678", "2378", "2579"]


for ID in idList:


    print(ID)
    driver.get(f"https://www.someWebsite/username/{ID}")

    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Access-Denied")
   
    print("error loading website")
    break
if not element:

    print("you may continue the for loop")
```

Mind you if the element showing the access denied page isnt present, i get an error that the 'Access-denied' element doesnt exist, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait for the webpage to receive the proper response. Using the following code, you can wait for the full response to load, and then take
appropriate action based on the outcome:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...
try:
    _ = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Access-Denied"))
        )
    print("error loading website")
    break
except TimeoutException:
    print("you may continue the for loop")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to loop through if the access denied is there then break.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
idList = ["8573", "85678", "2378", "2579"]

for ID in idList:
    print(ID)
    driver.get(f"https://www.someWebsite/username/{ID}")
    try:
        element=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Access-Denied')))
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```